# Deployed Android app read call logs return 0 result

Tags: android

I've developed an Android App for a client that will read the user's (my client's customers) call log to analyze the usage. The problem is, on some of the phones, the read returns zero result, and I have no idea what's causing the failure in reading the call logs.

My questions are these:

1. Is there anything I need to pay extra attention to, when reading call logs, like adding a wait period before reading the cursor (i.e. for slower phones)?

I never have this problem when running the app on my own phone (Android 7/Nougat), emulators (API 21 to 30, client want to support as many phones as possible). It's not happening in all the client's customers phone either, only some of them are showing this problem. Since it is deployed to users phone, I cannot study the run log to find out what's the reason of failure. This brings the second question:

2. Is there a way for an App to read the run log, without Android Studio attached to the phone? I may want to send the log content to a server so that I can retrieve the logs to study for the problem. If this is not the correct way to debug problems from a deployed app, what's the proper way to retrieve error logs, exception reports and crash report from a phone, that, I could never be able to set my hands on? (Because it'd be very awkward and simply impossible to ask some random person who don't know me to "bring your phone to my shop so I can study the problem in my App"...)

if it helps, here is the function I used to read the call logs:

```
private fun readCallLog(): String
{
    var callLogString = ""
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, "android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG") ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        val cursor: Cursor? =
            context.contentResolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null)
        val number = cursor?.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)
        val callDate = cursor?.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE)
        val callType = cursor?.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)
        val duration = cursor?.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION)

        if (cursor != null)
        {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                do
                {
                    val phon = cursor.getString(number!!)
                    val date = cursor.getString(callDate!!)
                    val dirc = cursor.getString(callType!!)
                    val dura = cursor.getString(duration!!)
                    var type = ""

                    if (dirc != null)
                    {
                        when (dirc.toInt())
                        {
                            CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE -> type = "OUTGOING"
                            CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE -> type = "INCOMING"
                            CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE   -> type = "MISSED"
                        }
                    }

                    if (phon != null && date != null && dura != null)
                    {
                        callLogString += "$phon; $date; $type; $dura; ${calendar.timeInMillis}\n"
                    }
                } while (cursor.moveToNext())
                callLogString = callLogString.trimEnd('\n')
                //Log.i("CALL LOG", callLogString)
            }
        }
        cursor?.close()
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No Call Log permission!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    return callLogString
}
```

Edit: I have to add that, the most probably reason for the problem is, the permission check returns NotGranted, but my client ensures me that the user HAS INDEED granted permission to access call log when asked earlier in the App.